# Number of different colourings of a grid of concentric circles up to rotation of annuluses

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions, cyclic-groups

If I have $n$ concentric circles so that each section (annulus or a central disk) is divided into 4 pieces
and allow the group $G= C_4 \times C_4 \times \ldots \times C_4$ to act on the set of colourings of the circles using $m$ colours by rotation of the annuluses.

Then how do I find the total number of fixed colourings by elements in $G$ so that I can use Burnside’s Lemma? It’s relatively easy to find the fixed number of colourings when an element of $G$ only rotates one annulus at a time however I’m not sure how to do this when more than one annulus isn’t acted on by an element.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll assume that you meant “is acted on” in the last sentence.

The number of colourings fixed by an element $g$ of $G$ is the product of the numbers of colourings fixed by the components, since for each annulus you can independently choose a colouring that is fixed by the corresponding component of $g$; see [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Everything else in the problem also factors, so you’ll find that the number of equivalence classes of colourings under independent rotations of the annuli is the $n$-th power of the number of equivalence classes of colourings of each annulus under rotations. Here, too, you could have obtained this result directly by arguing that the equivalence classes of colourings under independent rotations of the annuli are formed by independently choosing an equivalence class for each annulus, and then applying the multiplication principle.

Comment: I’m not sure how to work that out for each possible combination. There are like 4^n combinations.

Comment: @Anteater23: I don't understand. What do you want to work out? The answer doesn't require working anything out for $4^n$ combinations; it only requires to take the number for an individual annulus (which I assume you know how to work out using Burnside's lemma) to the $n$-th power.

Comment: There are $4^n$ elements in the group $G$ so I need to calculate the number of colourings fixed by every element in $G$ for Burnsides Lemma.

Comment: @Anteater23: No, it all factors. Denoting the components of $g\in G$ by $g_i$ and the number of fixed points of $a$ by $\#a$, we have

$$
\sum_{g\in G}\#g=\sum_{g\in G}\prod_i\#g_i=\prod_i\sum_{g_i\in C_4}\#g_i=\left(\sum_{c\in C_4}\#c\right)^n\;.
$$

Comment: As element (r,e,...,e) in G fixes m^{4n-3} colourings. I’m not sure we can just multiply. I think you’re considering a different group actions acting on each annulus and then taking the product? Slightly different. My thinking was consider this external product acting on the annuluses.

Comment: @Anteater23: It may well be that I misunderstood the question. In that case I'm probably not the only one, so you should probably define the group action that you have in mind more explicitly in the question. The first sentence in your last comment is compatible with how I understood the question, so if there's a misunderstanding, that's not where it is. (Each component $e$ fixes $m^4$ colourings, and $r$ (assuming that this denotes a rotation through $\frac\pi2$) fixes $m$ colourings, so the product is $m^{4n-3}$, as it must be.)

Comment: So if I consider the fixed colourings of a particular annulus and then do this for all annuluses. If I multiply all these answers I’ll get the number of fixed colourings for if I considered the group action acting on the annuluses together???

Comment: I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So I take one annulus calculate the number of colourings fixed by $e,r,r^2,r^3$ and add all these together. Then this to the power of $n$ is the answer if I considered the external direct product acting on the annuluses together?

Comment: @Anteater23: Yes, that sounds like we mean the same thing, and yes, just as you describe. I suggest that you try it on a small example with $2$ annuli to get a feel for it.

Comment: Is there a particular theorem that says why this works?

Comment: @Anteater23: There's the multiplication principle that I linked to in the answer. Other than that, it's just how sums and products interact, I guess you could view it as an application of the law of distributivity of addition and multiplication. Perhaps take another look at the displayed equation I wrote out in a comment above. If you understand why the sum and product sign can be interchanged like that (which is essentially distributivity), you should be able to see why this is a basic fact that doesn't require a theorem.

Comment: I don’t understand how you’ve written the formula above #g doesn’t mention the number of fixed points in particular annuluses

Comment: @Anteater23: No, it doesn't, but $\#g_i$ does. I defined the $g_i$ to be the components of $g$.

Comment: but In the third summation you say g_i is in C_4, not s component of g

Comment: Is the final answer: $\frac{m^4 + m^2 +2m}{4^n}$ ?

Comment: I said let $C_4$ act on each section of the wheel by rotation in a natural way and worked out the number of fixed colourings is $m^4+m^2+2m$ and then I said let $C_4 \times C_4 \times ... \times C_4$ act on the colourings of the wheel by rotation in a natural way where the ith $C_4$ acts on the ith section by rotation. I said a wheel colouring is fixed by an element of the external product if and only if it’s indivual sections are fixed colourings by an element of $C_4$

Comment: Hence the number of wheel colourings that are fixed by some element of the external product is the total number of combinations of colourings of sections which are fixed by an element of $C_4$ which is $(m^4 +m^2 +2m)^n$. Dividing by the order of the external product gives the number of different orbits in the wheel colourings set and thus the number of different colourings up to rotations of sectionals of a wheel.

Comment: The result in your last comment is correct, so I guess it's just a typo that the numerator isn't taken to the $n$-th power in the "final answer" further up?

Comment: Yes my mistake. Is my reasoning correct? I wanted to word it like this if it’s correct. Is it ok to say $C_4$ acts on a section by rotation? And likewise that the external product acts in the wheel by rotation. If not how would I say this?

Comment: @Anteater23: Much of it is correct, but you don't seem to distinguish clearly between the number of colourings fixed by individual elements and the sum of those numbers. E.g. you write that "the number of wheel colourings that are fixed by some element" is $(m^4+m^2+2m)^n$, but that's the sum over those numbers. Likewise for $C_4$. Note that the *total* number of colourings for one annulus is just $m^4$, so there can't be any single element that fixes $m^4+m^2+2m$ colourings. This is the sum over all elements of the number of colourings they fix, and it counts many colourings more than once.

Comment: I completely overlooked colouring being counted more than once! Would that not make my final answer wrong then since the number of fixed colourings for an annulus is not exactly $m^4 + m^2 +2m$ and thus this to the power of $n$ is not necessarily the number of different colourings of the entire wheel?

Comment: @Anteater23: My understanding was that you're trying to apply Burnside's lemma. To do that, you don't need the number of colourings that are invariant under some element; you need the sum over all elements of the number of colourings that that element leaves fixed. That sum is indeed $m^4+m^2+2m$, so your answer is correct. I thought this was clear, since I'd written that sum early on in the comments above.

Comment: I cant see and at all how you go from step 2 to step 3 in that equality. The swapping of sum and products.

Comment: @Anteater23: These comments are becoming too long. That's an application of the [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of addition and multiplication. I'd suggest that if that's not clear to you, you could ask a separate question on that. Or perhaps write it out for $n=2$ and multiply out the parentheses.

Comment: I know the distrubutivity law but it’s usually written differently and can’t see how it works here. As in a product of n independent sums goes to the summation over n variables of products.

Comment: When you have the sum before the product I’ve managed to rewrite this line using $n$ summation symbols. Now I know I can write it as product symbol then sum symbol! Thanks for your help.