# Distributivity of multiplication

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could someone explain why the following is true? Is there some theorem which says it is true?

$(x_{1,1} +x_{1,2} + \ldots + x_{1,m})(x_{2,1} +x_{2,2} + \ldots + x_{2,m})\ldots (x_{n,1} +x_{n,2} + \ldots + x_{n,m})$

Equals

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^m (\prod\limits_{j=1}^n x_{i,j})$

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true. Here is a counterexample: $4=(1+1)\cdot(1+1)\neq (1\cdot1)+(1\cdot1)=2$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597453/number-of-different-colourings-of-a-grid-of-concentric-circles-up-to-rotation-of/3597473?noredirect=1#comment7399767_3597473

Comment: Could you look at the answer to my question here. Would you be able to explain how he goes from step 2 to step 3 swapping the sum and the product

Answer (score 1):

The notation
$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^m x_{i,j}\right)$$
**literally means**

$$(x_{1,1} +x_{1,2} + \cdots + x_{1,m})(x_{2,1} +x_{2,2} + \cdots + x_{2,m})\cdots (x_{n,1} +x_{n,2} + \cdots + x_{n,m}).$$

I would not expect to find a "theorem" to this effect; although the $\prod$ and $\sum$ notations are rigorously defined, spelling out the notation with all the "$+\cdots+$" terms is an informal way helping us to understand what the rigorous definitions mean.

Observe that the formula with $\prod$ and $\sum$ is quite different from the formula you wrote. Hence it is easy to show a counterexample to the claim that your formulas are equal, as one answer already has done.

---

**Update:**
Based on your comment, you really should have explained in your question where you were getting your formulas, and the question as originally written should have included the link that you finally included in your comment.

What that link leads to is (among other things) the equation

$$\sum_{g\in G}\prod_i\#g_i = \prod_i\sum_{g_i\in C_4}\#g_i,$$

which I guess is where you get the idea that someone said you can "swap the symbols around."
But $C_4 \neq G$, so this equation is not at all the same thing as just swapping the order of a product and a summation.
Moreover, the equation can only be properly understood in the context of the original question from which it arose; otherwise how are we to interpret all those symbols? We need to know how $g_i$ and $C_4$ relate to $G$ and to each other.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597453/number-of-different-colourings-of-a-grid-of-concentric-circles-up-to-rotation-of/3597473?noredirect=1#comment7399767_3597473

Comment: Somebody said by distrubutivity you can swap the symbols around.

Answer (score 0):

This can be written in summation notation as,

$(\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{1,j})\cdot(\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{2,j})\cdots(\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{n,j})$

And simplified as:

$\prod_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{i,j})$

Comment: But somebody told me you can swap the signs around by distrubutivity.